# How likely would kids survive on a hostile land?

Tags: internal-consistency, psychology

I'm writing an adventure, adult novel where a group of children under the age of eleven have been left to camp on a dangerous grotesque island. 
My main character named Martin is afraid of everything in general, but is extremely smart about surviving/escaping the area.

But I don't want all the child characters to be intelligent, even the unlucky and kids would get eaten by the animals, not like in fairy tales. I want to make their reactions childlike and Martin strong. Intelligence is mainly for adults.
What should I do with the other child characters below Martin to make them act like real children would on a hostile island?

Comment: Depends on the kids & depends on WHY they are on the island. Did adults drop them there as a coming of age thing, or are they there by accident in a culture similar to our own? Children adapt quickly, so if you can give me a little more context, that might help. Kids are very different from society to society, depending on what's expected of them.

Comment: "Lord of the Flies" might be a good starting point.

Comment: What do you mean by "a grotesque island"? How big is it? What's the weather like? I was recently on Catalina island. As with most islands it does not contain any creatures that would hunt/ kill humans. What kind of predators do the kids face?

Comment: Intelligence is not mainly for adults. *Having been educated or trained* comes with age, because there has only been so much time to teach things to someone who is still a child, but education and intelligence are not the same thing.

Comment: @AarthewIII Like three miles big, close to the equator.                                 The predators see children as basic prey (I'm still developing them), making them merciless & man-eating like mammals or anything nearby like sharks (or smaller creatures such as amoebas & leeches)

Comment: "...would get eaten by the animals, not like in fairly tales." Actually, that is how many of the fairy tales actually go. People have been changing them over the last generation or two to sound nicer, but really people die a lot in the fairy tales. Goldilocks, Hansel and Gretel, Red Riding Hood, and more. They all died horrible, gruesome deaths.

Answer (score 3):

There is a series called Jeremiah, where, after a disease, everyone over 18 (or maybe yonger, as much to 12) dies off, leaving the kids to rebuild society and all.

That's one scenario. There, much of today's knowledge would be lost for many years to come.

Another possible case would be like the one in "The Lord of the Flies". There, many kids are left behind in an island after an accident, and they must survive. They evolve as much to make a little tribe with leader (and lots of troubles).

So, here are two plausible scenarios to think about.

Answer (score 1):

These are some of the reactions expected by the children in real life. Note that the realistic reactions of children are quite different from depicted reactions of children in movies and anime.

1- constantly nervous. will freak out at every shadow, every figure appearing at corners, even when someone suddenly shouts.

2- noisy. nervous kids (specially girls) have an extremely hard time quieting down. you would expect a constant noise of crying, complaining, praying, regretting and screaming. and yes this will easily give away their location to any predator (or monster).

3- many of the kids would turn very obedient and do as told by elders while a few would get hysteric and try to run away frantically. once they witness how an elder can protect (or hide) them, their expectations and commitment to that elder will increase rapidly.

4- most children (along with several adults) will lose their appetite. they would also not be able to relax and sleep (if the misadventure lasts for several days). in general, their nerves would get higher and higher strung while their physical energy and strength dives down.

Comment: Or their noise scares off the predators?

Answer (score 1):

There are some basic phases to follow

-**Fear**:The kids are scared by anything, even shadows

-**Panic**:The kids can't handle it anymore and go crazy

-**Religion**:Fear and panic will push them to pray fantasy characters like deities or superheroes...

-**Psycho trauma**:After the fear,panic,death of someone and realizing there's no big daddy or mommy in the sky to save them, the survived kids will have  their personality changed completely.

almost all  of them will become more violent and aggressive and faster at critical thinking , most of them will be violent to themselves and try to suicide cause realism tells them they have low chances to survive. And even if they get out alive, they can't live anymore with all the emotional weight they carry.

the others will most likely either die trying to avenge the fallen ones cause the desire of death is stronger than fear,is the human nature to transform fear into rage and hate to gain strength. Or if the traumatic event didn't transform them in beasts or killed them inside, they will hide and do their best to survive.